# rabbitmq v 3.4.0 Silent install Erlang Cookie Issue

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I have a problem when I install rabbitMQ Silently (not normal), It is installed successfully and I see the rabbitmq in services and started but when I try to run rabbitmqctl or rabbitmq-plugins I face the following error:

```
* Connection attempt from disallowed node 'rabbitmq-plugins1208079@WIN-IOBM5KICB89' **
```

I found a work around for this when I copy the .erlang.cookie from C:/{User} to C:/Windows, the problem is solved, any I dea why is this happening and if there is any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is used by the underlying erlang environment to decide to allow/block the connections. More information is [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)